# how to add class on table using javascript in tinymce?

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, tinymce

I have some problem to add class on table. 
I wanna this code

```html
<table></table>
```

become this code by click a button in tinymce.

```html
<table class="try-class"></table>
```

I have add button, and still cannot solve how to add code on tinymce table plugin.
thank you... :)

Comment: I would suggest reading this http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_addclass.asp (which is relevant to your question) and then add the code inside a script tag within your HTML file.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the `style_formats` option for the TinyMCE configuration file:

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/content-formatting/#style_formats

You can target a certain tag as being relevant for the style you wish to add.  For example:

```
style_formats: [
    {title: 'Red text', inline: 'span', styles: {color: '#ff0000'}},
    {title: 'Red header', block: 'h1', styles: {color: '#ff0000'}},
    {title: 'Table row 1', selector: 'tr', classes: 'tablerow1'}    
]
```

...would allow you to add a class `tablerow1` to a `<tr>` tag within the editor.

Answer (score 0):

I had hoped `style_formats` would have worked, but it did nothing for me. This is finally what I used to add custom classes to my tables:

```
table_default_styles: {},
table_default_attributes: { class: 'table table-bordered table-striped' },
```

This first removes all of the automatic styles tinymce adds (like width).
Then it overrides tinymce's default attributes with a class attribute where I specify the classes I want.

In my case I'm using Bootstrap, so I want tables to have Bootstrap classes.

Answer (score 0):

I use jQuery on the page to target the table:

```
<script>
    $table = $('table').addClass('table table-condensed table-responsive');
</script>
```